# org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData

Tags: java, spring-boot, database-connection, connection-pooling, application.properties

I have created a micro service and it runs fine in production for 3-4 weeks. Its a low volume service with few calls every couple of days. After 3-4 weeks all requests starts failing with below message in the logs

> 2019-04-15T22:33:17.628901587Z 2019-04-15 22:33:17.627  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : Error while extracting database name - falling back to empty error codes
>
> 2019-04-15T22:33:17.628928571Z org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: JZ0C0: Connection is already closed.

Upon restart app starts working normally for another few weeks.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

My application properties file looks like below

```
spring.datasource.max-active=6
spring.datasource.max-idle=0
spring.datasource.min-idle=0
spring.datasource.initial-size=1
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=30000
spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=60000
spring.datasource.remove-abandoned=true
spring.datasource.remove-abandoned-timeout=120
spring.datasource.validation-query= select 1
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.validation-interval=30
```

Comment: See, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html. What connection-pool library do you have?

Comment: I am using tomcat pooling. I am not sure what is causing connections to go stale

Comment: There is additional set of properties for tomcat datasource `spring.datasource.tomcat.*= # Tomcat datasource specific settings`. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

Comment: Any recommendations on what additional properties to try ? I can certainly try test-on-connect and test-on-return to true. However, i am curious i already have remove-abandoned to true on top of that i also have minimum pool size of 0 so how can i have stale connection that I am not getting it

Comment: `testOnBorrow`, `validationQuery`, `removeAbandoned`,`maxIdle`, `minIdle`, `initialSize`, `jdbcInterceptors="ConnectionState;StatementFinalizer(useEquals=true), SlowQueryReport"`,